# Is it "on the bed in my room" or "in my room on the bed"?

Tags: word-order, adverbials

1. She is on the bed in my room.
2. She is in my room on the bed.

Which of the above sentences is correct? Why?

Comment: Why do you think one has to be wrong? There is just a slight difference in emphasis.

Comment: 1 suggests she might be on another bed in a different room, 2 suggests she might be somewhere else in my room. But neither is ungrammatical; English doesn't have many rules about the order of preposition phrases.

Comment: [Assuming neither _she_ nor _is_ is emphasised]: (2) is the unmarked version, giving prominence to 'in my room', with 'on the bed' almost an afterthought. (1) either (a) gives prominence to  'on the bed' (this seen as the important factor; perhaps it's important that she rests) or (b) uses 'in my room' as an identifier (_which_ bed? ... the one in my room). In speech, intonation would distinguish 2a and 2b.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I parse those sentences absent any punctuation that might divide them into more than one clause, such as "She is on the bed — in my room."  with an implied verb.

> She is on the bed in my room.

She is on (the bed in my room).   **in my room** is part of the noun-phrase that is complement of **on**.

> She is in my room on the bed.

**on the bed** is a complement of **is**, predicated of **she**.

Both are grammatical.

Comment: Tim, are you sure that went through a grammar/spelling check?

Tim, Mari-Lou and Muuu Mu, don't you think that even though '… on the bed in my room' does not, '… in my room on the bed' does demand a comma, and not on the spurious ground that it might otherwise mean that the room is on the bed?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Sorry, I don't follow your meaning. Please tell me you're not talking about punctuation.

Comment: Sorry, Tim… try it! I happen to believe the only one part of your Post that doesn't need correction is 'Both are grammatical.' Other opinions might be available.

Comment: I don't see any other options. Venture an answer yourself and explain what you mean. Since I'm in the dark about what you mean by "try it".  Try what?

Comment: Note: Please don't let this conversation spiral any more out of control lest I be forced to lock this (or worse). Just disengage.

Comment: Thank you, Laurel!

Comment: Again, thanks… and almost separately, can anyone explain how at least one of Tim's and at least one of my Comments here have been deleted?

I assumed Tim took back one of his, for reasons of his own; why should he not?

However, I did not Delete my own Comment and if anyone else had, surely I'd have had some kind of message?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin  Here's my take on punctuation. Corridor doors often have the word PULL or PUSH engraved on them.  At least they do in the US. That sign tips you off about what to do with the door, but it is not *integral* to the functioning of the door. It is simply an aid for a person approaching the door. So too with punctuation. It doesn't make a textual representation of an utterance grammatical; it simply reveals the underlying clause structure, or *an* underlying clause structure if there is more than one way to parse the utterance.

Comment: Thanks, Tim, and how does that relate to the Question, or to any Comments here - including mine?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin In your first remark you brought up the issue of punctuation with "... demand a comma...".  My comment relates to punctuation.

Comment: Oh… back to Laurel to whom, again, thanks!